# Moving code from mercurial to TFS

Tags: mercurial, tfs

We are planning to move to TFS. While i hate it we have to do it for various reasons.

1. We have dev, staging and live branch. Do we move the source for each of the branch to TFS as separate folder and convert it to a branch later on?
2. Is it possible to take history along?
3. Is there a tool or a script which can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not been able to find a way to convert directly from Mercurial to TFS.  It looks like your best bet could be to convert your Mercurial repository to a Git repository and use [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) to push those changes to TFS.

I'm not familiar with Git or TFS so you'll have to do some more research to find out the exact steps but here's how I think that I'd go about it:

1. Convert your Mercurial repository to a Git repository (perhaps [this](http://hedonismbot.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/hg-fast-export-convert-mercurial-repositories-to-git-repositories/) will help)
2. Create your empty TFS repository
3. Clone your TFS repository using [this](http://git-tfs.com/) page as a guide
4. Use git to push your converted Mercurial Git repository to the TFS Git repository
5. Use git-tfs to push those changes to TFS

I don't know if that will copy all the history over or if you'll just have one check in with the final copy of the code.

Comment: If you need to do this on an environment other than Windows, Microsoft has released a cross platform tool called git-tf that is similar to git-tfs.  You can find that here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=261658

Comment: @user460025 It would be useful to know if this just brought over the latest version or the entire history.  If it's just the latest version I would think following this process is not worth it, why not just get the latest from mercurial then check it into tfs?